# Algorithm outputs correct answer but programming challenges gives me wrong answer

Tags: c++

I'm making an algorithm that simulates a minesweeper game. You have to input the number of rows and columns, followed by the bombs (which are represented by '*') and blank spaces, which are represented by any char.

In the output, you have to print the a matrix which shows '*' where there is a bomb, and the number of bombs on the borders of each blank space. Also, the output has to contain a "Field #x" before showing the resulting matrix, where 'x' is the number of the output

On my algorithm, I'm getting a right result - but when I send it to the online judge, it says the answer is wrong, so I think it might be a formatting issue. Where did I miss? The link for the exercise is right here http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=downloadproblem&probid=110102&format=html

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

int l;
int c;
int boleano = 0;
int cont = 1;
while (boleano == 0) {

    cin >> l >> c;

    if (c <= 0 || l <= 0 ||  l > 100 || c > 100) {
        boleano = 1;
        break;
    }

    char matriz[l][c];
    char aux[c];

     //  ESCANEANDO MATRIZ

    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        cin >> aux;
        for (int j=0; j<c; j++){
            matriz[i][j] = aux[j];
        }
    }


    int contador[l+2][c+2];

    // ZERANDO MATRIZ CONTADORA

    for (int i=0; i<l+2; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<c+2; j++) {
            contador[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }


    // ACRESCENTANDO VALORES DAS BOMBAS

    for (int i=1; i<l+1; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<c+1; j++) {
            if (matriz[i-1][j-1] == '*') {
                contador[i-1][j-1]++;
                contador[i-1][j]++;
                contador[i-1][j+1]++;
                contador[i][j-1]++;
                contador[i][j+1]++;
                contador[i+1][j-1]++;
                contador[i+1][j]++;
                contador[i+1][j+1]++;
            }
        }
    }


    // PRINT FINAL

    if (cont >1) {
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Field #" << cont << ":" << endl ;

    for (int i=1; i<l+1; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<c+1; j++) {
            if (matriz[i-1][j-1] == '*') {
                cout << matriz[i-1][j-1];
            }
            else {
                cout << contador[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
           cont++;
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: An extra new line at the end of the output is usually what's wrong.

Comment: I think I have to get all the inputs first, and then when someone inputs 0 0 it outputs all the answers it has got. Problem is, I don't know how to store all that data from the loop and then print it all in the output, since I don't know how many loops it is going to make. Any guess?

Answer (score 0):

You could insert an extra introduce an extra boolean which shows whether the current loop is the first loop.
In case it isn't and the current row count isn't equal to 0, you insert the extra new line. In case the formatting issue is because the following format is required:
[Nothing]
Field #1:
*100
2210
1*10
1110
[NewLine]
Field #2:
**100
33200
1*100
[Nothing]
I used the [Nothing] to indicate where there is no (more) new line.